# How do I merge datasets in H2O Flow on string columns?

Tags: h2o

I am trying to merge two datasets. The dataset on the left contains data about input variables. The dataset on the right contains data about output variable. The two datasets has a common column that contains data of type string. I am trying to merge them into a single dataset, suign the common column, in H2O Flow. When I call the merge operation I get following error:

ERROR MESSAGE: DistributedException from /10.151.9.92:54321: 'Operation not allowed on string vector.'

H2O is running on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the data type of the column you want to merge on is of type string. Merges are not allowed on columns of type string, so when you parse your datasets, set the data type of your merge column to `enum`. After that you should be able to do the merge.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, it seems weird that H2O Flow does not handle merging dataset on string columns and would force you to convert to Enum. I end up merging the two datasets using Python Pandas library before feeding to H2O. That worked for me.

Comment: the reason that the conversion to enum is necessary is because h2o-3 performs a sort before doing the merge. You can convert back to string afterward if needed. Alternatively, if you feel like this feature would be a nice add, you can create a request for it via h2o.ai's jira system. http://jira.h2o.ai. thanks!